# ArcGIS JavaScript ClassBreaksRenderer not working, layer shows only default symbol

Tags: javascript, geojson, arcgis, renderer

I'm adding a `ClassBreaksRenderer` to my ArcGIS map's `GeoJSONLayer` and for some reason only the default symbol is rendering.

```
  // Color Logic

  const low = {
    type: "simple-fill",
    color: "#fc8d59",
    style: "solid",
    outline: {
      width: 0.2,
      color: [255, 255, 255, 0.5],
    },
  };

  const medium = {
    type: "simple-fill",
    color: "#99d594",
    style: "solid",
    outline: {
      width: 0.2,
      color: [255, 255, 255, 0.5],
    },
  };

  const high = {
    type: "simple-fill",
    color: "#0d2644",
    style: "solid",
    outline: {
      width: 0.2,
      color: [255, 255, 255, 0.5],
    },
  };

  let renderer = new ClassBreaksRenderer({
    field: "sum_aqi_mean",
    defaultSymbol: {
      type: "simple-fill",
      color: "black",
      style: "backward-diagonal",
      outline: {
        width: 0.5,
        color: [50, 50, 50, 0.6],
      },
    },
    classBreakInfos: [
      {
        minValue: 0,
        maxValue: 1,
        symbol: low,
        label: "Low",
      },
      {
        minValue: 1,
        maxValue: 2,
        symbol: medium,
        label: "Medium",
      },
      {
        minValue: 2,
        maxValue: 3,
        symbol: high,
        label: "High",
      },
    ],
  });

  const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(layers)], {
    type: "application/json",
  });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const geo = new GeoJSONLayer({
    url: url,
    renderer: renderer,
    popupTemplate: template,
  });
```

When I add this layer to my map, it produces the following screenshot. The value in the popup is the value of that polygon's `sum_aqi_mean` value:

[Map only renders default symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5hKe.png)

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

Because elsewhere in my code I was dynamically building these polygons, I was actually mapping the raw data's `sum_aqi_mean` property to each polygon's `aqi` property.

Accessing the `aqi` field in the `ClassBreaksRenderer` instead works as expected.

```
let renderer = new ClassBreaksRenderer({
field: "aqi",
defaultSymbol: {
  type: "simple-fill",
  color: "black",
  style: "backward-diagonal",
  outline: {
    width: 0.5,
    color: [50, 50, 50, 0.6],
  },
}});
```